# Render new table row after jQuery ajax insert

Tags: jquery, web-services, row

I am using jQuery+webservice to add new row to the table. I am just interested what is a good way to fill the last inserted row with data?

I was thinking of three options:

- reload entire page? doesn't sound logical
- use updatepanel?
- somehow use returned set of data on success //don't really know how to do it

I appreciate any help

Comment: So what does the webservice do? Does it return the data for the row you want to add?

Comment: Webservice acts as an insert command. It just returns new recorID, but  it could also return the data of the new row. In what format should this data be return, and how to use it to build a new row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the web service method to return either an array of strings to insert as `<td>s`, or you want to return a POCO with properties that will give you a JSON object you can then use.

For example, using the array of strings approach, if you have the following web service method in a file called WebService.asmx:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] GetNewRow() {
    var listOfItems = new List<string>();
    // populate the listOfItems here
    listOfItems.Add("100");
    // more here
    return listOfItems.ToArray();
}
```

Then assuming a table on your page with an id of "table1" exists, your jQuery might look like:

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'WebService.asmx/GetNewRow',
    data: "{}",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        var $table1 = $('#table1');
        var contents = response.d; // store the returned array in a variable
        // loop through the array and build up the HTML for the new row.
        // there are much better ways to do this, but I can't think of them right now...
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
           html += '<td>' + contents[i] + '</td>';   
        }
        // add the new row to the table
        var $newRow = $('<tr></tr>').append(html).appendTo($table1);
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        // notify the user of the error
        // e.g. by adding it to the table with a special error class
        var $table1 = $('#table1');
        var $newRow = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('errorRow').append('<td></td>').find('td').text(msg.responseText);
        $table1.append($newRow);
    }
});
```

There are a stack of other ways you could do it, too.

**Note:** None of my code has been tested, and I won't be around for the next few days to check in.

I recommend you look at the amazing Dave Ward's site, http://encosia.com - it has heaps of helpful posts about calling web services in .Net from jQuery code.

Good luck!

Comment: Is it possible to return a multidimensional array?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never tried, but I would assume so. You might be better to return an array of POCO's, though, as that will then give you some JSON objects to loop through in your javascript, and facilitate more readable code.